# Anyone see what's wrong with this sticky sidenav jquery script

Tags: jquery

Trying to get this sticky side nav working correctly. At the moment it overflows the footer in the live site but works fine in my jfiddle prototype.

Live example with issue.

https://tregothnan.co.uk/tea-herbal-infusions/

```
$(function () {
var stickyNavTop = $('.nav').offset().top;

var stickyNav = function () {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scrollTop > stickyNavTop) {
        $('.nav').addClass('sticky');
    } else {
        $('.nav').removeClass('sticky');
    }
};

stickyNav();

$(window).scroll(function () {
    stickyNav();
});
});
$(function () {
var top = $('#sidebar').offset().top - parseFloat($('#sidebar').css('marginTop').replace(/auto/, 0));
var footTop = $('#footer').offset().top - parseFloat($('#footer').css('marginTop').replace(/auto/, 0));

var maxY = footTop - $('.left-col-content').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function (evt) {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 100) {
        if (y < maxY) {
            $('#sidebar').addClass('stickyside').removeAttr('style');
        } else {
            $('#sidebar').removeClass('stickyside').css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: (maxY - top) + 'px'
            });
        }
    } else {
        $('#sidebar').removeClass('stickyside');
    }
});
});
```

Working fiddle here;

http://jsfiddle.net/katch/cmp20k3w/

Comment: Your live example doesn't appear to be implementing a stickyNav, so we can't see the issue.

Comment: Just had to comment it out as it broke some other features...